# c# exception file is being used by another process

Tags: c#, file, exception, process

i have trouble with the following two functions. Both have a indentical basic scheme but first one work, second one causes an exception at marked line("File is used by another process").

```
    // this works
    public static void EncryptFile(string FileName)
    {
        string ToEncrypt = null;

        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
        {
            ToEncrypt = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName, false))
        {
            string Encrypted = Encrypt(ToEncrypt, true);
            sw.Write(Encrypted);
        }
    }
    // this works not - see commented lin
    public static void DecryptFile(string FileName)
    {
        string ToDecrypt = null;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
        {
            ToDecrypt = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        // here comes the exception
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName, false))
        {
            string Decrypted = Decrypt(ToDecrypt, true);
            sw.Write(Decrypted);
        }
    }
```

I have tried with an additional Close() after read and write, but this works not too.
I hope, somebody can help.

Thanks

Torsten

Answer (score 0):

Is the function called from multiple threads? If yes you may want to declare a static object on class level and place a lock statement around the entire body of that method. Like this:

```
private static Object syncObject = new Object()
// this works not - see commented lin
public static void DecryptFile(string FileName)
{
    lock(syncObject)
    {
        string ToDecrypt = null;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
        {
            ToDecrypt = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        // here comes the exception
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName, false))
        {
            string Decrypted = Decrypt(ToDecrypt, true);
            sw.Write(Decrypted);
        }
    }
}
```

Also could you, just for fun, comment the StreamReader statement and try to run the method again? If it still doesn't work, check if you've that file open in a texteditor or something alike by using ProcessExplorer or something similiar.

**edit**
could you comment the StreamReader part? So that it looks like this:

```
 public static void DecryptFile(string FileName)
 {

    //string ToDecrypt = null;

    //using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
    //{
     //   ToDecrypt = sr.ReadToEnd();
    //}
    // here comes the exception
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName, false))
    {
        string Decrypted = Decrypt(ToDecrypt, true);
        sw.Write(Decrypted);
    }

}
```

also could you try to open an exclusive FileStream on that file before the StreamReader and once after the StreamReader but before the StreamWriter? http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tyhc0kft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also could you try and use another file for that method?

Comment: No, function is not used by multiple threads. I also closed all other applications like explorer could block the file. This is very confusing, because first function is in principle the same and it works. I also commented out the part throwing the exception, than it works. So error is clearly localized, Thanks.

Comment: edited my question. I'm almost convinced that there is something else blocking that file since StreamReader is usually non-exclusive and even if it were still open, you should be able to edit that file.

oh and another thing: Could you set a breakpoint on the using statement of the StreamWriter? When the debugger arrives there, try to open the file in a texteditor and make some change to it and try to save it. Also check your code and make sure that you aren't using that file anywhere else.

Comment: Done.Error found. A StreamReader was open before function call.Stupid error. Sorry and thanks a lot.

Comment: weird, I was under the impression that a StreamReader is usually non-exclusive. Meaning you can still write to a file while a StreamReader is open...guess I was wrong there.

Comment: // Decrypt file
            if (Encryption) CryptorEngine.DecryptFile(FileName);
            // Read element data
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName);
            while ((row = sr.ReadLine()) != null)// Decrypt file
            if (Encryption) CryptorEngine.DecryptFile(FileName);
            // Read element data
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName);
            while ((row = sr.ReadLine()) != null)

Comment: This worked not:
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName);
 // Decrypt file
 DecryptFile(FileName);
 // Read element data
 while ((row = sr.ReadLine()) != null) ......
This works now:
 // Decrypt file
 DecryptFile(FileName);
 // Read element data
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName);
 while ((row = sr.ReadLine()) != null) ......

So it was possible to open two StreamReaders pointing to same file, but seemingly
its not possible to write until both are closed.

Comment: ah, in that case I missunderstood the term 'exclusive', thank's for clarifying that!